# How to lowercase and replace spaces in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

In PHP:

```
$output = preg_replace("/[^a-z]/","_",strtolower($input));
```

How to do the same in a BASH script?

Comment: I think you can run PHP in console mode where it takes input from STDIN and prints to STDOUT

Comment: Alternatively, use Perl: `perl -wple '$_ = lc $_; $_ =~ s/[^a-z]/_/g'`

Comment: This doesn't work: $output = $input >> php -r preg_replace("/[^a-z]/","_",strtolower(fgets(STDIN)));

Comment: What do you expect your snippet to do? It is not valid shell syntax at all. Maybe your question is how to send input on STDIN to a program from the shell?

Comment: The question seems to be: What are the equivalent commands to achieve the same effect. I find the quite adequate and I am surprised where all the confusion comes from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Requires bash4 (tested with 4.3.48).

Assuming you never want a upper case character in the value of the variable `output`, I would propose the following:

```
typeset -l output
output=${input// /_}
```

- `typeset -l output`: Defines the variable to be lowercase only. From `man bash`:

  > When the variable is assigned a value, all upper-case characters are converted to lower-case.
- `output=${input// /_}`: replaces all spaces with a underscore.

BTW: There is also `typeset -u variable` to define it as "all upercase".
See `man bash`.

---

Update: While revisiting, I realized that my answer matches the question question title, but not the PHP code. In the PHP example, all characters that are **not** `a-z` are replaced with a underscore. So, if `input` contains a colon or a comma, those would also be replaced by underscore.

So here is code that also matches that:

```
typeset -l output
output=${input//[^a-z]/_}
```

Finally a quote from the answer of @micha-wiedenmann :

> One thing to note though is that the BASH version uses patterns instead of regular expressions. For example, the pattern `*` is similar to the regular expression `.*`. And the pattern `?` is `.`.

Check the man-page and search for "Pattern Matching".

Comment: Thank you for teaching me about `typeset -l`!

Comment: In bash-3.2, I get "typeset: -l: invalid option," and as of man bash the options are only -a, -f, -i, -r, -t, and -x

Comment: Upgrading to bash-4.4 it works

Comment: @simpatico  Updating to bash 4.* was a good idea. Most people here will assume we talk about bash4 when answering questions. BTW: Bash5 came out a few days ago, but I would wait before updating to that.

Comment: @user7369280, macos latest default is still bash-3.2. The latest on macports is 4.4 and to use it the script has to start with #!/usr/bin/env bash

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for **Pattern substitution** (`${parameter/pattern/string}`) and **Case Modification** (`${parameter,,pattern}`)? If so, you will find more in [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) under the topic of **Parameter Expansion**.

```
$ a="FOO BAR BLUB"
$ tmp=${a// /_}
$ echo ${tmp,,}
foo_bar_blub
```

One thing to note though is that the BASH version uses patterns instead of regular expressions. For examplem, the pattern `*` is similar to the regular expression `.*`. And the pattern `?` is `.`.

Comment: Micha, I quoted your last sentence in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

php in bash?

```
$ php -r "echo preg_replace(""/[^a-z]/"",""_"",strtolower($argv[1]));" A1B2C
a_b_c
```

Comment: Please include $input and $output variables in your bash line

Comment: @simpatico You will really need to learn about how the shell works. There are no "input variables" and "output variables". You need to pipe the values into the called program. You will need to learn shell programming, but this site is not about teaching how to program.

Comment: OR: I learned how the shell works and wrote several bash scripts before, but there is a gap in my knowledge that I'm humbly asking about here. Grateful to those who know and answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
output=`php -r "echo preg_replace("/[^a-z]/","_",strtolower($input));"`
echo $output
```

`$input` is simply a variable defined in the bash script.

Alternatively, [@user7369280's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7369280/user7369280) also works since bash4+.